# Excel VBA reduce processing time of Autofilter Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 1 worksheet that contains 14k rows and 36 columns. Columns 24 to 36 contain formulas (ao find and vlookup formulas).

The Calculation is set to manual.

I created a test macro that sets an autofilter on the dataset and I included 4 filter criteria (see code below). The strange thing is that when I run this macro for the first time it takes 109 seconds to run, the second time it takes 17 seconds, and the third and consecutive times it is around 0,3 seconds. I find this really strange. How can this happen and what can I do to get the 0,3 seconds the first time?

Thanks.

```
Sub test() 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet    
Dim rng As Range    
Dim PG()

PG = Array(“441”, “445”, “446”, “447”)
Set ws = Worksheets(“Notificaties”)
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Set rng = ws.Range(“A1”)
Set rng = ws.Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))

With rng    
.AutoFilter    
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=”TWAP*”    
.AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=”<>*II*”    
.AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:=”TRUE”    
.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=PG, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `Criteria1:=PG` with `Criteria1:=(PG)`.  Any better ?

Comment: @Johan ; you may want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question.  If the code works and needs optimized, that would be the more ideal site.

Answer (score 0):

If the formulas have not been updated, they will be updated by the first autofilter command, even with Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual. So before using Autofilter, you may want to update the formulas with a command like the following:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```